Issue with Seurat Object Column "doublet_class"
This line of code in my standard workflow
DimPlot(combined_seurat_object, group.by = "doublet_class")

produces the error Error in [.data.frame(data, , group) : undefined columns selected. I am trying to add in the column doublet class in this chunk of code
for(i in seq_along(seurat_objects)) {
  obj <- seurat_objects[[i]]
  
  obj[["pct_mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(obj, pattern = "^MT-")
  top20 <- names(sort(rowSums(obj@assays$RNA@counts), decreasing = TRUE))[1:20]
  obj[["pct_counts_inTop20_genes"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(obj, features = top20)
  obj[["log1p_nCount_RNA"]] <- log1p(obj[["nCount_RNA"]])
  obj[["log1p_nFeature_RNA"]] <- log1p(obj[["nFeature_RNA"]])
  print(colnames(obj@meta.data))
  outlier_df <- data.frame(row.names = rownames(obj@meta.data))
  for (metric in c("pct_counts_inTop20_genes", "log1p_nCount_RNA", "log1p_nFeature_RNA", "pct_mt")) {
    M <- obj@meta.data[, metric, drop = FALSE] # ensure it's a data frame even for one column
    mean_abs_dev <- mad(M[[1]]) # Use the first (and only) column
    outlier <- (M[[1]] < median(M[[1]]) - 5 * mean_abs_dev) | (M[[1]] > median(M[[1]]) + 5 * mean_abs_dev)
    print(sum(outlier))
    outlier_df[[metric]] <- outlier
  }
  
  obj <- AddMetaData(obj, metadata = rowSums(outlier_df) > 0, col.name = "outlier_status")
  obj <- subset(obj, subset = outlier_status == FALSE)
  
  doublets <- scDblFinder(obj@assays$RNA@counts)
  obj <- AddMetaData(obj, metadata = doublets$classifications$classification, col.name = "doublet_class")
  
  seurat_objects[[i]] <- obj
}

seurat objects is a list of seurat objects, i just want to add the column of whether its a doublet or not
I tried reworking the code and tweaking it but nothing worked
